# How to reduce size of the UITableViewCell at runtime in Objective C?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have made a custom cell in the storyboard having height 300, which include label and imageView, but for some case if I had not received image from the response I want to decrease the cell height and want to remove the imageView from the cell so that it could not be visible to the user .
In that case I just want to show the text in the label. 
How could I achieve that? I know its silly question but I am stuck here. 
Your help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Just add condition on heightForRowAtIndexPath.

If image not there then decrease the height

Comment: but below imageview i have buttons too... if i decrease height it will also hide that.

Comment: Then you need to change frames of the buttons in cellforrowatindexpath. Decrease the y  value of buttons accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I have wrote some basic code fro your understanding how table view cell resizing works (irrelevant of custom or basic cells).

```
@interface MasterViewController ()

@property NSArray *objects;
@end

@implementation MasterViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    _objects = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ImageList" ofType:@"plist"]];
}


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return _objects.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = object[@"text"];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:object[@"image"]];
    return cell;
}

//- (NSString *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
//    return _objects.allKeys[section];
//}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return [_objects[indexPath.row][@"image"] length] ? 60.0f : 30.0f;
}

@end
```

In above code you prime focus should be on method `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and it's code line `return [_objects[indexPath.row][@"image"] length] ? 60.0f : 30.0f;`.

Now as if you load image dynamically from server then keep track for image of which cell is been loaded and call `[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:<#(nonnull NSArray<NSIndexPath *> *)#> withRowAnimation:<#(UITableViewRowAnimation)#>]` with relevant index path. Also make sure you update `image loaded` information in your `dataSource` i.e. `_objects` in above code.

I have uploaded [code here](https://github.com/rptwsthi/DevelopmentSupportWorkspace). Check `UITableViewTest` in workspace.